# Having too much expectations or having too high expectations

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference, can both be used and which one is proper ?

Comment: "too much" should probably be "too many". With that change, they mean different things & which you use depends on what you are trying to say. You need to give more context, e.g. an example sentence where you want to use the phrase.  In any case, if you are learning English, then this Q. would be more appropriate on our sister site [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) would probably be more suited to your questions.  I'm voting to move this question accordingly.

Comment: First of all, you can't have *too **much** expectations*. You can only have *too **many** expectations*. (Although, I suppose you could have *too much expectation*, where it's used as a singular mass noun.)

Comment: Charles Dickens had [Great expectations](https://books.google.ro/books/about/Great_Expectations.html?id=tQEwAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y).

Answer (score 1):

'Much/many' is an adjective expressing quantity or amount. Many of this sort of adjective have plural forms which must be used when the noun is plural. Another example of a quantative adjective would be 'few' and 'a little'.

'Expectations' is a plural noun so the plural form 'many' must be used.

'High' is an ordinary adjective, nothing special about it! In English, adjectives do not normally agree with noun number: we talk about 'high expectations', plural, or 'high expectation', singular.
Using a modifier of an adjective,such as 'too' or 'very', does not affect the adjective. So, 'too high an expectation' is correct, and 'too high expectations' is also correct. 
I hope that helps!